# Rotational angular momentum P of symmetric rotor molecules

Tags: spectroscopy

I'm reading Hollas Modern Spectroscopy and having trouble to visualize the rotational angular momentum $P$, which appears in the rotational term values. 
\begin{equation}
F(J, K)=B J(J+1)+(A-B) K^{2}
\end{equation}

1. What is the difference between $P$ and $J$ since they both represent angular momentum. Also later on there is the mention of $P$ in the Stark effect and the projection of $P$ on $z$-axis is given by:
   \begin{equation}
   \left(P_{J}\right)_{z}=M_{J} \hbar
   \end{equation}
   which is the same with $l_{z}=m_{l}\hbar$. It is also stated that the molecule rotates around $P$. Does this mean $P$ coincide with/parralel to a $C_{n}$ axis?
2. For a linear molecule/diatomic molecules $K=0$. Why is this the case?
   (A diagram would be of great help)